# git - How to pull a branch from a specific branch

Tags: git, caffe

I'm now working on a branch of BLVC/caffe: which is

```
https://github.com/yosinski/caffe.git
```

Now if I want to add a feature which is from a pull request from original branch:

```
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/2935
```

How can I add this feature into my working project.

Do I need to pull the original repos first before I pull this PR?

Answer (score 1):

Add a new remote (say, `bvlc`) with the URI of the original repository into your working repository (skip it if already done).

```
$ git remote -v        # check if remote already added or not

$ git remote add bvlc <original-repo-uri>          # 'bvlc' indicates original repository
# e.g. git remote add bvlc https://github.com/rmanor/accuracies.git
```

Now, Add the feature into your working project by simply Pulling the PR-branch (branch from which the pull request is created) into your local repository.

```
$ git pull bvlc <pr-branch-name>
# e.g. git pull bvlc accuracies
```

Update the remote of your working repository.

```
$ git push origin HEAD
```

Comment: Hi what if the original repo didn't approve the PR?

Comment: And in my case what is "<pr-branch-name>"

Comment: in my case, the repo I wanna get is https://github.com/rmanor/accuracies

Comment: 1. if the original repo doesn't approve the PR, you can keep the changes in your repo (since it's already pulled the changes into your repo). 2. <pr-branch-name> = the branch name of original repo in which the PR is created.

Comment: I still don't get it. So in my case I should do
git remote add bvlc https://github.com/ronghanghu/caffe.git
which is not the original repo(a forked repo).
then git pull bvlc "????"

Comment: the repo I wanna pull is a forked repo from bvlc/caffe. And I'm now in the branch of bvlc/caffe(deconv-deep-vis-toolbox branch). I do git remote add bvlc https://github.com/rmanor/accuracies.git then git pull bvlc master. but nothing change????what did i do wrong?

Comment: I guess the changes are in `accuracies` branch. Try this: `git pull bvlc accuracies`

Comment: yeah. I did so. which give me a `permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Comment: Add the `HTTPS` link instead `SSH`. Update your  bvlc by `git remote set-url bvlc https://github.com/rmanor/accuracies.git`. Then try again.

Comment: thanks alot. It works. but why is there still some files missing. I mean the file in accuracies branch is not show up after I successfully did git `pull bvlc accuracies`

Comment: This should not be. Make sure the files exists in `accuracies` branch https://github.com/rmanor/accuracies/tree/accuracies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144185/discussion-between-pwan-and-sajib-khan).